# Bad request: Invalid json on open-elevation api

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to get the elevation of some points with latitude and longitude. I came across open-elevation and realized that it would do what I wanted. However, I get 400 error code, and a json object with the following message:

> {error: "Invalid JSON."}

My code is the following:

```js
function get_altitude () {
  let data = {
    "locations":
    [
      {
        "latitude": 10,
        "longitude": 10
      },
      {
        "latitude":20,
        "longitude": 20
      },
      {
        "latitude":41.161758,
        "longitude":-8.583933
      }
    ]

  };
  fetch('https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup', {method:'POST', body:data})
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
get_altitude();
```

Please note that the data variable is a copy of the one they show on their documentation.
Is there any obvious solution for this problem? I am fairly new to fetch, so I wouldn't be surprised if I had any glitch on my request.
Thank you!

Comment: Try if this helps --> `body: JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: Unfortunately  it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it! After analyzing their source code, I figured out that the variable they call in order to obtain the json data will return None if the content-type of the request is not set to 'application/json'. Actually, they have an example in their documentation where they use 'content-type': 'application/json', but that's all they mention about it. For those newbies like me who want to set the correct content-type, you will have to set mode to 'cors'. In the end, my code looked a bit like this:

```
let options = {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: new Headers({'content-type': 'application/json'}),
   mode: 'cors',
   body: JSON.stringify(data)
  };
fetch('https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup', options)
```

It also won't work unless you use JSON.stringify(), as suggested by Peter B.